# Restrict block visibility by page url

Tags: 8, blocks

Can I restrict the block visibility only show for `/worker/*/` but not `/worker/*/...`?

Comment: Not through the default UI, but you can do it through code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [block_exclude_pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_exclude_pages) was created for these types of scenarios

[image]